# Change ImageView image inside onClick event

Tags: android

I have an ImageView working as a button in my program. I need it to be an ImageView since I want just the image to be shown, not the borders.

This button is a lamp, if the data in database says it's visible, the lamp must be "on", when you click the button, it will check the data from bank and change it to "off" if it's on and vice-versa.

**So, the change of image will happen inside a onClick event.**

Here is my code:

```
btnVisualizar.setClickable(true); 
btnVisualizar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            if (visivelBanco.getText().equals("Y")) {
                btnVisualizar.setImageResource(this.getResources().getIdentifier(
                    "drawable/visible_off", null, this.getPackageName()));
            } else {
                btnVisualizar.setImageResource(
                    this.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/visible_on", null, this.getPackageName()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(), 
                "Falha ao modificar visibilidade do item!", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

However the compiler doesn't recognize the method getResources() and getPackageName().

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciatted.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in there refers to the `onClickListener`.

Use [Activity].this instead of this, where [Activity] is the name of the Activity

Comment: Hello Vikram.... thank you for your help. Well... this really helped the code to compile, however even so, the code is not changing the image, yet. This could should change the image of btnVisualizar on an OnClick event. Here is my modified code thanks to your help: btnVisualizar.setImageResource(EdicaoActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/visible_off", null, EdicaoActivity.this.getPackageName()));

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String uri = "drawable/visible_off"
btnVisualizar.setImageResource(EdicaoActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, "drawable", EdicaoActivity.this.getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Hello Intathep, thank you for your help. Well... I tried this one and even so, the image doesn't change. It just changes when I close and open the activity. Is there anything like a refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use the `R` class to obtain the identifier of your drawable. For example:

```
btnVisualizar.setImageResource(R.drawable.visible_on);
```

You should not need to go messing about with `getResources()`.

Comment: Thank you tomtheguvnor. Your code also compiles. However even so it doesn't change the image in the ImageView... I saw through debuger that it is getting inside and it also changes the data in the database as visible/not visible. But unhapilly it doesn't change the image right away as it should. =( Anyone else? Any help is appreciatted!

Comment: Does your `OnClickListener()` get called? Also, try calling `invalidate()` on the `ImageView` after you have switched the image and see if that helps.

Comment: Hello tomtheguvnor... well... the OnClick event is getting called and it is getting inside the method. Anyways it's not changing the picture. So, I tried something different. I did a brand new project with just one image and the code above. Now it works PERFECT! The only difference is that my code updates the visibility of the button in database and also several buttons (btnVisualizar) are created. What could be happening? Strange errors in Android! =P